# How to check the value of a dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, promise, protractor, bdd

I am trying to read (using protractor and BDD) the default values of certain dropdowns. To do this, I have tried several lines of code but none of them works.

Here is the code that I am using, the console.log is not being executed for some reason. Why?

```
checkDropdownAssignment: function(dropdown,defaultValue) //Function to check the value assigned to a dropdown
{
    let texto=[];

    $$('* option:checked').each(function(element, index) { // Execute this operation for each element of the website
        element.getText().then(function (text) { //Get text of the element in order to compare it with the endpoint afterwards.
        texto.push(index.toString()); // Add one more component to the vector
        texto[index]=text; // Save the text in a variable visible outside of this function.
        console.log(texto[index]);
        });
    });
},
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$$('*option:checked').all(by.tagName('option')).getAttribute('label').then(function(value){
 for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++){
  expect(value).toContain(arayOfExpectedResults[i]);
 }
});
```

Here you get an array with all the labels inside the dropdown and compare them with the expected result, or use the array the way you want.